# Intermittent very slow access to hosted site

Tags: networking, routing

I have a website which is hosted on a virtual host. It is normally quite responsive, but in the past few weeks I have had periods when it was taking several minutes to load a page.

The site has very little content and very few users (hasn't been launched yet). There are several sub-domains with Drupal, Moodle and MediaWiki installs. MediaWiki and Drupal 7 seem to be a lot worse than Drupal 6.

The hosting company have spent some time looking at it and are adamant the problem isn't their end, and there is nothing wrong with the site content/setup. They say it may be a routing issue.

My ISP is BT Infinity (fibre). I access a wide range of websites all the time, I only ever get problems with my own site.

If it is relevant, sometimes it works fine, other times it seems to get into a mode of taking ages to load a page. I have also noticed a possible pattern, if I am working on my site, then I go off and do something else in a different tab for a while, when I go back to my site it is in slow mode.

Bit stuck, I am locked into long term contracts with the ISP and the hosting co, but now suddenly I can't maintain my site, and they are both saying it is the other guys fault. Any suggestions for getting to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 0):

## Testing Company problems:

First make a static http page.  Try to access that instead of one with dynamic content.  If your problem is with this content then you have a problem with 1 of the 2 (or both) of the companies.

then a static https page (if that's a thing)

## Resolution for static pages:

A conference call between help desks is usually a fun way to bring everyone to the table.

Dynamic page issues are more interesting because it could be you.  Take a look at the apache/drupal logs and see if there is anything interesting going on.  Attacks? Scraping?  Spiders? A coder that didn't know the new rules on x.  Put this site on your local machine and run it if you haven't done that already.  then you can do things like profile the code etc..

Hope this helps